# Ruby on Rails set a specific time for a DateTime object in a Time Zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I know that calling...

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

will return me a DateTime object in the Pacific Timezone.  Is there a way to use `in_time_zone` to return a DateTime at a specific time instead of just now so that I don't have to convert from UTC time with something like this

```
 DateTime.new(year, month, day, hour, min).in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above is okay but I think this is a better solution for my purposes of going back and forth between multiple time zones seamlessly.

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)').change({hour: 13, minute: 30}).in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

Comment: As of now, in the api, the option for minutes is min: http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/change

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
my_time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"  
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[my_time_zone].parse("2015-02-12 21:57:00")
```

Which should return a DateTime in the supplied Time Zone.